# maximum value of: $\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a}$

Tags: inequality

Let: $|a|<1$. Find the maximum value of:

$$\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a}$$

Here is what I tried:

Using Cauchy:

$$\sqrt{1-a^2} \leq \frac{(1-a)+(1+a)}{2}=1$$

$$\sqrt[4]{1-a}\leq \frac{1+\sqrt{1-a}}{2}$$

$$\sqrt[4]{1+a} \leq \frac{1+\sqrt{1+a}}{2}$$

So we have: $$LHS<3$$ and can't find the maximum.

Comment: In the title you ask for the maximal value, and in the question body you ask for the minimal value. Please clarify.

Comment: I fixed it @MartinR

Comment: Note that $LHS = 3$ for $a=0$, so your claim that “$LHS < 3$” is not correct. Actually, $3$ is the maximal value.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that $f(a)$ is even. Also $$f’(a)= \frac{-a}{\sqrt{1-a^2}} -\tfrac{3}{4}(1-a)^{-3/4}  + \tfrac{3}{4}(1+ a)^{-3/4} $$

When $a>0$, the first term of $f’(a)$ is obviously negative. We also have that $\tfrac{3}{4}(1-a)^{-3/4}  > \tfrac{3}{4}(1+ a)^{-3/4}$ when $a>0$ so $f’(a) < 0$ when $a>0$. Therefore $f(a)$ has minima when $a=\pm1$.

Comment: I think $a$ can't be $\pm1$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(a)=\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a}.$

Thus, $f$ is a concave function, which says that the infimum is or $f(1)$ or $f(-1).$

Can you end it now?

Comment: I think $a$ can't be $\pm1$ because the condition

Comment: @Lục Trường Phát Yes, because $-1<a<1$ and $f$ is a concave function.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an elementary proof:

Take $a \in [-1,1]$. We have

$$\sqrt{1-a}\sqrt{1+a} \ge 0$$
$$2+2\sqrt{1-a}\sqrt{1+a} \ge 2$$
$$(\sqrt{1-a}+\sqrt{1+a})^2 \ge 2$$
$$\sqrt{1-a}+\sqrt{1+a} \ge \sqrt 2$$
$$\sqrt{1-a}+2\sqrt[4]{1-a}\sqrt[4]{1+a}+\sqrt{1+a} \ge \sqrt 2$$
$$(\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a})^2 \ge \sqrt 2$$
$$\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a} \ge \sqrt[4] 2$$
$$\sqrt{1-a^2}+\sqrt[4]{1-a}+\sqrt[4]{1+a} \ge \sqrt[4] 2$$

and for $a=\pm 1$ we have equality, so that's the minimum.

Comment: The condition is $|a| <1$ so i think $a$ can't be $\pm1$

Comment: If you are not able to understand what is happening and how this (and the others responses)  answer your question, you need to step back, try to understand what a minimum and a maximum is, probably develop a geometric intuition of what is a function, an open interval, extrema, etc.